# How to change an object's property in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, button

I have a function that sets a property in an object to false if it's true and true if it's false. Yet every time the function runs the object doesn't get affected.

```
$scope.menuButtons = [{header: "beaded", isActive: false}, 
                      {header: "laced", isActive: false}
                     ]

$scope.activeButton = function(isActive) {
    isActive == true ? isActive = false : isActive = true;
};
```

Here's the HTML

```
 <div ng-repeat="b in menuButtons">

 <div ng-click="activeButton(b.isActive)" class="shop-navbar-button">{{b.header}}</div>

 </div>
```

I'm using the isActive value to see if the button is active so I can use a different class. For some reason the isActive value in the $scope doesn't get affected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass in `b` instead of `b.isActive`. The boolean is just being passed by value, so re-assigning the value will have no effect on `b.isActive`.

Comment: Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can change from this:

```
<div ng-click="activeButton(b.isActive)" class="shop-navbar-button">{{b.header}}</div>
```

to this:

```
<div ng-click="b.isActive=!b.isActive" class="shop-navbar-button">{{b.header}}</div>
```

You will NO need the auxiliar function. It is cleaner and more angular way.